# c# serialization I only get the root close in string

Tags: c#, xml

I want to serialize a class to string.
I use this code to serialize it to string:

```
root root = new root();
rootHeader header = new rootHeader() { 
   SystemName = "pontaz", 
   SystemVersion = 1, 
   SessionId = 1, 
   CommandName = "Connect", 
   ConnectOption = 0 
};

// get it to xml and to string
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;
settings.Indent = false;
StringWriter StringWriter = new StringWriter();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(StringWriter,settings);
XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
XmlSerializer MySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(root));

MySerializer.Serialize(writer, root, namespaces);
string s = StringWriter.ToString();
```

When its run it I get back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><root />
```

but it should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <Header>
      <SystemName>OTHERSYSTEM</SystemName>  
      <SystemVersion>1.00</SystemVersion><SessionId>1</SessionId> 
      <CommandName>Connect</CommandName>  
      <ConnectOption>0</ConnectOption>  
   </Header>
</root>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure you added your `rootHeader` to `root` element ?

Comment: Yes its added in the class part, but even so it should be '<root></root>' at minimum in the string, not just root end.

Comment: @Tory `<root />` and `<root></root>` are equivalent - the serializer is free to use either format.

Comment: @Tory Is the code you posted the code you are actually running? If so, then Mark's comment is completely correct. If not, then please post the *actual* code you are running, or an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are declaring a new instance of `rootHeader` but not actually using it anywhere.

Comment: Assuming that you do add class *rootHeader* to *root* are you sure that your `rootHeader` is `[Serializable()]` ?

Comment: @MarkBenovsky `[Serializable]` is not related to `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Add *rootHeader* to *root*

First of all you need to be sure that after you create new *root* element and *rootHeader*, you add *rootHeader* to *root* element:

```
root root = new root();
rootHeader header = new rootHeader() { 
   SystemName = "pontaz", 
   SystemVersion = 1, 
   SessionId = 1, 
   CommandName = "Connect", 
   ConnectOption = 0 
};

// add rootHeader to root element somewhere here
// before serializing it...
```

**root** element can have **rootHeader** marked as XmlAttribute

#### Static/Private field serialization

You said that you add *rootHeader* to *root* in code, be sure that you do **not** add it as a **Static** field and it **is Public**.

All fields that you want to serialize must be public and not static.

> .Net serialization serializes instances; static fields do not belong
>   to an instance.

This is all that I can suggest you to try from the code and info you provided.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see where you add rootHeader to root .. It would explain why you get this result.

Comment: this isn't a answer

Answer (score -3):

You can use the XmlSerializer built-in class to make your job easier, the class also writes the output to a file

```
// Namespace containing the serialization class
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// instances the serializer and tells wich type it will serialize
XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass));

 // Create a new file stream to write the serialized object to a file
TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\output.xml");
// Serialize and write on file
SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, TestObj);

// Close stream writer
WriteFileStream.Close();
```